# Trying to get the url from a different tab in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having trouble getting the URLs from the different tabs in one spreadsheet.

I have been able to get the URL for the sheet that I want and the first page, however, I cannot figure out how to get the link to any specific tabs with names in that one sheet.

```
function nameCheck() {
    var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID HERE');
    var getFiles = targetFolder.getFiles();
    while (getFiles.hasNext()) {
      var file = getFiles.next();
      if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet') {
        if (file.getName() == 'TESTING'){
          Logger.log('Success ' + file.getName())
          Logger.log('Overview: ' + file.getUrl())
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to set the `gid` url parameter. I'll let you research more about that.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance I figured it out!

Comment: If you think your solution will be useful to others, consider posting it as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Glad you solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
function ztest() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (i = 0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() == 'NAMEOFTAB'){ // replace with the name of your tab
      Logger.log(sheets[i].getName()); // double checking along the way
      Logger.log(sheets[i].getSheetId()); // double checking along the way
      var URLgid = 'LINKHERE#gid=' + sheets[i].getSheetId() //replace link here with the general link
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveSheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[i]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('RANGE').setValue('REPLACE'); //replace the range and what you are substituting 
      Logger.log(URLgid) // testing to see what the link is
    }

  }
}
```